# CoreData + CloudKit + SwiftUI List CPU usage and Energy Impact(OverHead) are high

Tags: swiftui, cpu, cloudkit

I make a app to record clothes information. (SwiftUI + CoreData + CloudKit)

[image: 200 items]
It currently shows 200 saved items as a list.

[image]

[image]

1. When I build the app(Add New Item also Energy Impact will be high), the Energy Impact goes up to 'Very High'. I don't know what the overhead is, but the cause seems to be CloudKit. If I disable Background Modes -> Remote notifications, ICloud -> CloudKit and build the app, the Energy Impact drops to half.

[image]
2. CPU usage is high when scrolling through the list, on average I use 30-60% and as high as 70-80%. I don't know what is causing this. I thought it might be an image issue, so I removed the image code, but it still showed high CPU usage.

Because of the above two issues, I notice my device heating up when adding new items or while scrolling.

**CoreData**

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

final class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let cloudKitContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
    init() {
        cloudKitContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Item")
        guard let description = cloudKitContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("Failed to init persistent container")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

        cloudKitContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error {
                print("Faild Load CoreData. \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        cloudKitContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        cloudKitContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    }
}
```

**MainList**

```
struct MainListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @SectionedFetchRequest<String, ItemEntity>(sectionIdentifier: \.contentViewSectionHeader, sortDescriptors: [
        SortDescriptor(\.orderDate, order: .reverse),
        SortDescriptor(\.createdDate, order: .reverse)
    ]) private var items: SectionedFetchResults<String, ItemEntity>
    
    @State private var showingAddView = false
    @State private var searchText = ""

    @State private var selectedItem: ItemEntity? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { sections in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(sections) { item in
                                MainListRowView(item: item)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                }
                        }
                        .onDelete { indexSet in
                            delete(section: Array(sections), offSets: indexSet)
                        }
                    } header: {
                        headerView(date: sections.id, count: sections.count)
                    }
                    .listRowSeparatorTint(.strokeColor)
                    .listSectionSeparator(.hidden)
                }//.id(UUID()) 애니메이션 이상
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("보관함")
            .toolbar(content: toolbarContent)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddView) {
                AddView()
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
                DetailView(item: item)
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "제품명, 브랜드, 색상, 리뷰, 핏, 사이즈 등")
            .onChange(of: searchText) { newText in
                items.nsPredicate = newText.isEmpty ? nil : predicate(by: newText)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - View
    private func headerView(date: String, count: Int) -> some View {
        LabeledContent {
            Text("\(count)")
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        } label: {
            Text(date)
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    private func toolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button {
                showingAddView = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.heremesColor, .gray.opacity(0.1))
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: - searchBar Predicate
    private func predicate(by text: String) -> NSPredicate {
        NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@ || brand CONTAINS[cd] %@ || color CONTAINS[cd] %@ || review CONTAINS[cd] %@ || fit CONTAINS[cd] %@ || #size CONTAINS[cd] %@", text, text, text, text, text, text)
    }
    
    //MARK: - CoreData
    private func delete(section: [ItemEntity], offSets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offSets {
            let item = section[offset]
            moc.delete(item)
        }
        save()
        print("Success Deleted")
    }
    
    private func save() {
        withAnimation {
            guard moc.hasChanges else { return }
            do {
                try moc.save()
                print("Success Save to Core Data")
            } catch {
                print("Failed Save to Core Data, \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainListRowView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainListRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: ItemEntity
    @State private var contextMenuImage: UIImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        LabeledContent { } label: {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 14) {
                MainListImageView(item: item)
                mainListInfoView
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
    
    private var mainListInfoView: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
            Text(item.unwrappedName)
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            Text(item.unwrappedBrand)
            
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                Text(item.unwrappedSize)
                Text("•")
                    .font(.caption2)
                Text(item.unwrappedFit)
                Text("•")
                    .font(.caption2)
                Text(item.unwrappedReview)
            }
        }
        .font(.footnote)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        .lineLimit(1)
    }

    private var symbol: String {
        item.unwrappedUnit == "cm" ? "cm" : #"""#
    }
}
```

**MainListImageView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainListImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: ItemEntity
    @StateObject private var imageHolder = ImageHolder()

    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
    private let lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.4

    var body: some View {
        MainListImage
            .onAppear {
                print("== MainListImageVIew onAppear ==")
                guard !item.unwrappedThumbnailImageData.isEmpty else { return }
                imageHolder.image = UIImage(data: item.unwrappedThumbnailImageData)
            }
            .onChange(of: item.unwrappedThumbnailImageData) { newValue in
                print("== MainListImageVIew onChange ==")
                imageHolder.image = UIImage(data: newValue)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("== MainListImageVIew onDisappear ==")
                imageHolder.image = nil
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                rulerImageView
            }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var MainListImage: some View {
        if let thumbnailImage = imageHolder.image {
            Image(uiImage: thumbnailImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 56, height: 56)
                .background(Color(uiColor: .quaternarySystemFill))
                .clipShape(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                )
                .overlay {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                        .stroke(Color.strokeColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
                }
        }
        else {
            Image(systemName: "tshirt.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary.opacity(0.55))
                .frame(width: 56, height: 56)
                .background(Color(uiColor: .quaternarySystemFill))
                .clipShape(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                )
                .overlay {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                        .stroke(Color.strokeColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
                }
        }
    }
    
    private var rulerImageView: some View {
        Image(systemName: "ruler")
            .imageScale(.small)
            .font(.footnote)
            .fontWeight(.regular)
            .foregroundStyle(.primary.opacity(0.64))
            .padding(6)
            .background(
                Circle().fill(.regularMaterial)
            )
            .overlay (
                Circle().stroke(Color.strokeColor, lineWidth: lineWidth)
            )
            .offset(x: 12, y: 0)
            .opacity(item.saveRealSize ? 1 : 0)
    }
}


final class ImageHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
}
```

1. Is the reason for the high energy impact when building the app for the first time due to loading all the items? The 'overhead' is quite high, but I don't know what exactly the overhead is.
2. Is the high CPU usage when scrolling through the list due to unnecessary redrawing of the view? I've defined an ObservedObject in each subview to reflect the item information as it changes in real time.

Comment: See [Demystify SwiftUI performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/)